# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 18, size is 18

Tags: java, android, exception, arraylist

```
int i = 0; //used for getting item position
for (Iterator<CustomObject> iterator = mAdapter.getItemsData().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {

    if (mAdapter.getItemsData().get(i).getPriceTier() != 1) { //if statement throws error
        // Remove the current element from the iterator and the list.
        iterator.remove();
        mAdapter.removeFromItemsData(i);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/223929/4484340) stackoverflow answer, I iterate through my arraylist of CustomObject. Custom object is just a POJO class with setters and getters. The setters and getters have different data types, such as int, String, double etc.

mAdapter.getItemsData returns the araylist from the adapter class.

```
//method just notifies the RecyclerView that an item was removed.
public void removeFromItemsData(int position){

    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

Here is the exception

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 18, size is 18
>               at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
>   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308) at
>   com.test.TestActivity$5.onClick(TestActivity.java:280)  at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

CustomObject class

```
public class CustomObject{
    private String name;
    private int distance;
    private String category;
    private String id;
    private double rating;
    private String ratingColor;
    private String prefix;
    private String suffix;
    private int priceTier;
    private String currency;
    private String phone;
    private String twitter;
    private String url;
    private String menu;
    String address;
    String city;
    String state;
    String postalCode;
    double lat;
    double lng;
    String review;
    int reviewCount;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String userIconPrefix;
    String userIconSuffix;
    String secondsReview;

    public CustomObject() {
        this.name = "";
        this.distance = 0;
        this.setCategory("");
        this.id = "";
        this.rating = 0;
        this.ratingColor = "";
        this.prefix = "";
        this.suffix = "";
        this.priceTier = 0;
        this.currency = "";
        this.phone = "";
        this.twitter = "";
        this.url = "";
        this.menu = "";
        this.address = "";
        this.city = "";
        this.state = "";
        this.postalCode = "";
        this.lat = 0;
        this.lng = 0;
        this.review = "";
        this.reviewCount = 0;
        this.firstName = "";
        this.lastName = "";
        this.userIconPrefix = "";
        this.userIconSuffix = "";
        this.secondsReview = "";
    }

    public void setSecondsReview(String secondsReview){
        this.secondsReview = secondsReview;
    }

    public String getSecondsReview(){
        return secondsReview;
    }

    public void setUserIconSuffix(String userIconSuffix){
        this.userIconSuffix = userIconSuffix;
    }

    public String getUserIconSuffix(){
        return userIconSuffix;
    }

    public void setUserIconPrefix(String userIconPrefix){
        this.userIconPrefix = userIconPrefix;
    }

    public String getUserIconPrefix(){
        return userIconPrefix;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
        //todo if String firstNAme == null, then return "a foursquare user"
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName){
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setReviewCount(int reviewCount){
        this.reviewCount = reviewCount;
    }

    public int getReviewCount(){
        return reviewCount;
    }

    public void setReview(String review){
        this.review = review;
    }

    public String getReview(){
        return review;
    }

    public void setLng(double lng){
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public double getLng(){
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat){
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public double getLat(){
        return lat;
    }

    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode){
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }

    public String getPostalCode(){
        return postalCode;
    }

    public void setState(String state){
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getState(){
        return state;
    }

    public void setCity(String city){
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCity(){
        return city;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address){
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return address;
    }

    public void setMenuUrl(String menu){
        this.menu = menu;
    }

    public String getMenuUrl(){
        return menu;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrl(){
        return url;
    }

    public void setTwitter(String twitter){
        this.twitter = twitter;
    }

    public String getTwitter(){
        return twitter;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone){
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPhone(){
        return phone;
    }

    public String getCurrency(){
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency){
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public int getPriceTier(){
        return priceTier;
    }

    public void setPriceTier(int priceTier){
        this.priceTier = priceTier;
    }

    public String getSuffix(){
        return suffix;
    }

    public void setSuffix(String suffix){
        this.suffix = suffix;
    }

    public  String getPrefix(){
        return prefix;
    }

    public void setPrefix(String prefix){
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    public double getRating(){
        if(rating > 0){
            return rating;
        }
        return 0; //TODO display symbol if rating not found
    }

    public void setRating(double rating){
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public Integer getDistance() {
        if (distance >= 0) {
            return distance;
        }
        return 0; //TODO display symbol if distance not found, like N/A
    }

    public void setDistance(int distance) {
            this.distance = distance;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

How data is added

In onCreate of activity, I instantiate Recyclerview. RecyclerView takes an arraylist, so I pass an empty one.

```
List listTitle = new ArrayList(); //empty arraylist
mAdapter = new Fragment1Adapter(listTitle);

RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Later on in an AsyncTask, I add the items to the Adapter.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) { 
    CustomObject poi = new CustomObject ();

    if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("venue")) {
        poi.setName(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("venue").getString("name"));
        poi.setId(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("venue").getString("id"));
    }
    mAdapter.addItem(poi);
}
```

Here is the addItem class

Declared at top of adapter class `private final List<FoursquareVenue> itemsData;`

```
public void addItem(FoursquareVenue data) {
        itemsData.add(data);
        notifyItemInserted(itemsData.size() - 1);
    }
```

Comment: First line of the exception clearly says whats wrong. Index starts from 0 to size - 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Since you our chat and your edits:

You need to add and remove the items to your ArrayList and them notify adapter of change.

```
CustomObject poi = new CustomObject ();
if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("venue")) {
    poi.setName(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("venue").getString("name"));
    poi.setId(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("venue").getString("id"));
}
listTitle.addItem(poi);// Add to ListArray
```

Then loop through your ArrayList to remove items.

---

You've just muddled yourself up a bit in how you are trying to access your data.

There is a problem that you are creating an iterator of CustomObjects, and parsing it to the data type of `mAdapter.getItemsData()`.

Removing the element from the iterator should remove it from the list.

```
 for (Iterator<CustomObject> iterator = mAdapter.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
     CustomObject itemsData = iterator.next();
     if (itemsData.getItemsData().get(i).getPriceTier() != 1) { //if statement throws error
            // Remove the current element from the iterator and the list.

            iterator.remove();
        }
        i++;
      }
    CustomObject itemsData = iterator.next();
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: With 'CustomObject itemsData = iterator.next();' I can only access the setters and getters. I need to access the arraylist, which is located inside my adapter class. Thanks for trying ti help :)

Comment: I'm trying to loop through an arraylist, and remove all data at the selected position, which doesn't meet certain criteria. All data is displayed in an RecyclerView, which is why I call notifyItemRemoved(position); :)

Comment: .@Hey you Since I have a RecyclerView,which needs an adapter, which needs an arraylist, I create an empty arraylist and pass that to my adapter class. I later add in the data, by having a method which adds the data inside of the adapter class.                                                                   Method: 'public void addItem(FoursquareVenue data) {
        itemsData.add(data);
        notifyItemInserted(itemsData.size() - 1);
    }'

Comment: .@Hey you added CustomObjects class